# how to get mobile number from contact

Tags: java, android

My application require to pick a contact from contacts list, then get ONLY the name and mobile number from the chosen contact to store them in the application, I successfully get the name, BUT how can I verify that the contact has a mobile number (not a home) then get the number?

And how can I check if the contact has one or more mobile numbers?

Comment: When you get a phone number from the contact, you can check its type.  Have a look at Phone.TYPE_xxx constants.  At the same time, keep in mind that the type of the phone number is set by the owner of the device and in many cases these types will not be correct.  For example, on my phone, most contact phone numbers are mobile numbers, yet they are saved with type "TYPE_CUSTOM" and show in the contact details as "DEFAULT".  Oh, and just looking at the number will not give you the answer either.  Your best bet is to rely on TYPE_xxx of the phone number despite it being unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

In android Contact name and number is save in different ContentProvider so for take contact_id from below code

```
  cur=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER +" > 0", null, null);
      cur.moveToFirst();
      while(cur.isAfterLast()==false){
        //    Log.e("Name is:",cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
              Fid=Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));

              int id=Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
              Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null, null, null);

              pCur.moveToFirst();
              while (pCur.isAfterLast()==false) {
                  int idinner=Integer.parseInt(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
                  if(idinner==id){ 

//Add id to Array

                 }
                 pCur.moveToNext();
            }
          cur.moveToNext();
      }
```

and than this id you can get mobile number and other details

```
public String getNo(String[] no){

    String seleContact="";  
//  String[] contactNos=new String[no.length];
    for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++){
        if(no[i].trim().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            break;
        }
        int id=Integer.parseInt(no[i]);
        //Cursor cur=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID +" = "+id, null, null);
        //cur.moveToFirst();

        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+"="+id, null, null);
        pCur.moveToFirst();

        while(pCur.isAfterLast()==false){
                 if(Integer.parseInt(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)))==(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)){
    //               String uname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)).toString();
                     String tempMoNo=pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     Log.e("Activity result selelength is",String.valueOf(seleContact.length()));
                     String[] temp=tempMoNo.split("-");
                     String MoNo="";
                     int le=temp.length;
                     for(int j=0;j<le;j++){
                         MoNo +=temp[j];
                     }

                     if (seleContact.length() > 0) {
                            seleContact += "," + (MoNo);
                        } else {
                            seleContact += (MoNo);
                            }            
                 }
            pCur.moveToNext();
             }
        pCur.close();
    }

    return seleContact;
}
```